# SQL Complex Search Query With Multiple Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'm trying to achieve something that Im not sure how to do it. I'm working on a website based on ASP Classic and SQL 2008, IIS7. In search page I have option to have couple value per query like `default.asp?q=one|two|three&q2=four|five|six` .
What Im trying to do is to use wildcard in case my queries dont have value and have ability to search couple word in one column at the same time in case my query has couple value. Here are what I want to do:

1. If query has value then go fine that in database (Which is pretty simple)
2. If query has couple value separated with "|" sign then split them and search for all of them.
3. If query does not have value at all, then use wildcard and do not search
   for anything.

So to achieve this I've tried couple thing but didn't get any success. Here is the example of my code.

One -----------

```
@style nVarchar(150) = ''
Select * FROM mytable WHERE CONTAINS(style, @style) AND ...
```

I can manage to split the query to something like `'"* value1 *" OR "* value2 *"'` to get the best result out of CONTAINS but This one is working if "style" has value. If style does not have value there is no wildcard so I can retrive all data without filtering down the database.

Two ---------------

```
@style nVarchar(150) = ''
Select * FROM mytable WHERE style LIKE '%' + @style + '%' AND ...
```

With LIKE clause I can use wildcard like `'%'` in case style does not have any value but I cannot search couple value in the same column.
So, keep in mind I'm using "Stored Procedure" since this is kind of complex and I need to use this in couple places. I will have have 10-12 query for this search.
Any Idea will help me to get this going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem is with values separated by "|". In SQL 2008 you can use Xml functions to transform the string into a table and query it against your base table:

```
DECLARE @style VARCHAR(MAX) = 'value1|value2|value3'
DECLARE @v XML 
SET @v = '<r><n>' + REPLACE(@style, '|', '</n><n>') + '</n></r>'

SELECT * FROM mytable
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS v FROM @v.nodes('//n') AS t(c)
) t
WHERE style LIKE '%' + t.v + '%'
```

Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for your time. It does help but would you kindly explain the OUTER APPLY a little bit? Like what happend in line "SELECT c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS v FROM @v.nodes('//n') AS t(c)". Thanks a lot.

Comment: OUTER or CROSS APPLY is an operator that allows invoking a table function for each row returned by a query. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=SQL.90).aspx) on SQL Server Books online, it's well explained there. The subquery SELECT c.value... is used to extract a rowset from the Xml created based on the "value1|value2|value3" text. nodes() function returns the nodes specified by the XPath "//n" and c.value('text()[1]'...) extracts the text. The index [1] is required by value() method to indicate the first text node.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I will go ahead and read that documentation. If I have couple query, I have to duplicate this times to my queries?

Comment: yes, you have to. If the queries use the same filter criteria, you can use a temporary table to store the rowset obtained from your values and use that instead of the subquery. Smth like `CREATE TABLE #t(v varchar(50))`, then `INSERT INTO #t SELECT c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS v FROM @v.nodes('//n') AS t(c)`, then `SELECT * FROM mytable OUTER APPLY #t WHERE style LIKE '%' + #t.v + '%'`